# How to access element in array via command line in ruby?

Tags: ruby, command-line

Given a simple code in file `test.rb`:

```
def todo_list(todo_selector)
    library = ["Get a cat", "Get a dog", "Build a fighting ring"]
    puts "Your current step in todo-list is:\n#{library[todo_selector]}"
end

ARGV.each { |todo| todo_list(todo_selector) }
```

How am I able to call this method with an index via command line? 
Normally I would use `test.rb 1`, but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from test.rb:17:in `<main>'
    1: from test.rb:17:in `each'
test.rb:17:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `todo_selector' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  todo_list
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you are calling `todo_list` function, you need to pass `todo` and not `todo_selector`

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for one element, take care to convert `String` into `Integer` in order to access the `Array` by index.

```
selector = ARGV[0].to_i
todo_list(selector)
```

For an array of arguments: `ARGV.each{ |i| todo_list(i.to_i) }`

Comment: Thank you! I used it this way and works as intended:

`ARGV.each { |todo| puts todo_list(todo.to_i) }`